# How to get ALL Mastodon accounts followers using API or web scrapping?

Tags: python, data-collection, mastodon

I want to get all the accounts followers by using the Mastodon API. In the documentation https://docs.joinmastodon.org/methods/accounts/#followers it is written that the maximum number of results to return can be 80. Is there another way to get a complete result?

Currently I have used the API in Python and Postman and the results are as to be expected limited to a maximum number of 80. Been thinking if teh snscrape can be a solution.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Have you tried using pagination parameters listed in the docs?

Comment: No I have not. This is my first time using an API and I'm not familiar with both the concept and the implementation. I will look into it. Thank you for your input.